# Добавление строк в ArrayList и вывод на экран размера и элементов списка

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.set(1, "списек");
list.set(2, "инвентарских");
list.set(3, "предметов");
list.set(4, "в");
list.set(5, "поездяльнике");

int a = list.size(); 
System.out.println(a);

for (int b = 1; b != 6;) {
    System.out.println(list.get(b));
    b++;
}
```

Задачи:

1. Создать список строк (`ArrayList`).
2. Добавить в него 5 различных строк.
3. Вывести его размер на экран.
4. Использовать цикл для вывода его содержимого на экран, каждое значение с новой строки.

Код без ошибок, но задачу не выполняет. Почему?

P.S. Задача с JavaRush.
P.P.S. Я импортнул `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чтобы установить значение в какой либо позиции, там должны быть элементы.  поэтому set() у вас упадет. Вам нужно добавить эти элементы, потом установить значение

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(7);

    list.add("");
    list.add("");
    list.add("");
    list.add("");
    list.add("");
    list.add("");
    list.add("");
    list.set(1, "списек");
    list.set(2, "инвентарских");
    list.set(3, "предметов");
    list.set(4, "в");
    list.set(5, "поездяльнике");

    int a = list.size();

    System.out.println(a);

    for (int b = 1; b!=6;) {
        System.out.println(list.get(b));
        b++;
    }
```

P.s. на самом деле вам нужно упроситть код до этого:

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("списек");
    list.add("инвентарских");
    list.add("предметов");
    list.add("в");
    list.add("поездяльнике");


    System.out.println(list.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }

    // либо

    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: да пробовал уже

Comment: хотите сказать. что не работает? http://ideone.com/Qt609l

Comment: @SeniorPomidor вывод на экран можно и ещё упростить: `list.forEach(System.out::println);`.

Comment: @Regent знаю. не хотел "усложнить" для юзера.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("списек");
        list.add("инвентарских");
        list.add("предметов");
        list.add("в");
        list.add("поездяльнике");

        System.out.println(list.size());

        list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Какой-то странный у вас цикл. Должен быть таким: `for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)`. Или даже так: `for(String string: list)`.

Ну и нет никакого смысла добавлять так, как вы добавляете. Проще вот так: `list.add("1");`

Также принято и полезно объявлять переменные с типом супер-класса/интерфейса. Т.е.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Все ваши способы перепробовал уже :(

Comment: @user258851, ну, значит надо у создателя алгоритма проверки выяснять как он код проверяет. Так-то да - и ваш и мой код делают одно и тоже)

Answer (score 0):

Stream.of("списек", "инвентарских", "предметов", "в", "поездяльнике").forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).